# SSIS expression

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

Anybody have any idea why this SSIS expression is not working

The derived column name is `from_service_date_yyyymmdd`

The expression is

```
(DT_STR,4,1252)from_service_date_yyyy + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)from_service_date_mm,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)from_service_date_dd,2)
```

`from_service_date_yyyy`, `from_service_date_mm` and `from_service_date_dd` all have valid values

The output from the derived column transformation does not have `from_service_date_yyyymmdd`. I can't figure out why.

Comment: What is the data type of your `from_service_date_` columns?

Comment: What does _The output from the derived column transformation does not have from_service_date_yyyymmdd_ mean? Are you saying that this column is not added to your data flow? What do you see if you double click the output line and check the metadata tab - is it in there? You might need to screenshot your derived column transform for clarification

Comment: @DickRosenberg Welcome to Stackoverflow, After i saw your profile you asked 3 questions and get helpful answers and many comments but you didn't made any reply... when asking questions you have to reply for the one who give you answers. if an answer solved your issue you have to accept it, else you have to give a reply. it is start by taking [Stack OverFlow Tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about this community

Answer (score 1):

your expression looks fine, but you missed the brackets in the columns names, and you have to cast columns to `DT_WSTR` instead of `DT_STR` because `RIGHT()` function [result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/right-ssis-expression) is of type `DT_WSTR`, and cast the whole result to `DT_DTR` if needed

```
(DT_WSTR,8,1252)((DT_WSTR,4)[from_service_date_yyyy] + RIGHT("0" + 
(DT_WSTR,2)[from_service_date_mm],2) + RIGHT("0" + 
(DT_WSTR,2)[from_service_date_dd],2))
```