# SSIS FOR EACH SMO

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, smo

When I open a `FOREACH LOOP CONTAINER` and choose `Foreach SMO enumerator` I get the wrong screen. What can i tell my DBA to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to close VS and reopened it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be caused by the `Target Server Version` in the `Project Properties`. The new installation of Visual Studio had it defaulting to `vNext`. Switching it to `Installed SQL Server version` may fix this problem.

You can follow this similar problem it may helps you:

- [Missing Enumerator in Foreach Loop Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595565/missing-enumerator-in-foreach-loop-editor/43596314#43596314)

Comment: That turned out to be the answer! For some reason the default TargetServerVersion is SQL Server 2017 and I am running SQL Server 2014. Once I changed it I got the right screen,...While I'm at it, how to I change the default?  Thanks...Dick

Comment: @DickRosenberg if this answer solved your issue you have to accept it. And if you find it helpful you have to upvote it. You can learn more at the [Tour page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I would love to accept it, as it answers my question. I can't find anyplace on the screen to accept it...Dick

Comment: @Dick it's the green check under the voting number please take the [tour]

Comment: You can read how it is done at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @DickRosenberg you've got the informed badge which means you have read the Tour page, why still not accepting or upvoting this answer. also i answered your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332470/ssis-expression from few months without getting any reply.